# Corona SDK IAP unsure how to unlock items

Tags: ios, lua, in-app-purchase, coronasdk

I am programming my app in corona sdks and am attempting to implement IAP into the app. I am using the sample code from http://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/09/03/tutorial-understanding-in-app-purchases/

What I don't get is how:

```
local function removeAds( event )
   if event.phase == "began" then
      event.target:setFillColor(224)
   elseif event.phase == "ended" then
      event.target:setFillColor(255)
      if system.getInfo("targetAppStore") == "amazon" or system.getInfo("targetAppStore") == "google" then
         store.purchase( "com.acme.superrunner.upgrade" )
      else
         store.purchase( { "com.acme.superrunner.upgrade" } )
      end
   end
   return true
end

local buyBtn = display.newImageRect("images/buy_button.png", 614, 65)
group:insert( buyBtn )
buyBtn.x = display.contentCenterX - 465
buyBtn.y = 430
buyBtn:addEventListener( "touch", removeAds )
```

com.acme.superrunner.upgrade is never mention in the main.lua or utilities.lua files. Am I missing something, how does  store.purchase( { "com.acme.superrunner.upgrade" } ) equate to something actually being unlocked in game. Thanks so much for any help! Is there another IAP file I need or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*com.acme.superrunnerupgrade* represents the ID of the store item for which you want the purchase to get initiated. This is usually configured in the Store's (Google play, Apple, Amazon) configuration.

After you configure your item / reward in the store, initiating a purchase to that item would take your user to the respective store item and carry out the payment process.

If the payment is completed, iTunes on the phone will get your app/game active and the callback function will be called.

In App Purchase for IOS are setup using iTunes connect. You can read about the process on the folliwing link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: So for iOS, where do i go to configure the purchases? I have iTunes connect set up with the IAP, but that never says what the user gets when buying the item, such as Coins = Coins + 100

Comment: Also, as I relook over the sample code for the main.lua, when is the function for transaction call back be called

Comment: You can change things like Coins = Coins + 100 in the callback function. I've explained in the edit when the callback function is triggered.